# ArcMap QGIS different distortion

Tags: qgis, arcmap, shapefile, distortion

I have a problem with a shapefile (EPSG:31287 MGI_Austria_Lambert). I tried to solve it on my own, but I just have no clue as to what's the error.

So I use a basemap from basemap.at (WMTS: https://www.basemap.at/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml -> EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator). When importing the basemap and then the shapefile in QGIS it looks like a weird distortion (Austria shapefile), the Polygons (which represent houses) are not exactly over the houses in the basemap, but a few meters away. When I do the same in ArcMap, there is no Problem and every Polygon matches the house in the basemap.

But I need to export it as KMZ or KML and when I do so, and then import it in Google Earth I get the same distortion like in QGIS)

I really hope someone has a clue or knows where the problem stems from.

ArcMap: [image]

QGIS: [image]

Comment: When you export the shapefile to KML/KMZ, are you using QGIS or ArcMap?

Comment: This looks like a projection issue. Possibly QGIS isn't automatically detecting the right projection when you load the shapefile. Make sure the correct projection is set under layer properties.

Comment: I exported it with QGIS and with ArcMap, both with the same result. They also have the same CRS(both in qgis:  EPSG:31287 - MGI / Austria Lambert - Projected  and  Arcmap: Projected Coordinate System: MGI_Austria_Lambert)

Comment: Most probably, your SHP file set is using Esri's version of PRJ.

Comment: Ist there a way to change this? So to make it work in qgis?